# Mostrar o HTML apenas de uma div

Tags: html, jquery, html5

Tenho uma função que gera formulário dinâmico, este formulário e carregado através de um GET via Jquery e mostra o formulário montado em uma div.

preciso pegar somente o código fonte desta DIV, alguém sabe uma maneira de fazer isso?

Este e um exemplo do código que precisaria separado!

```
<div id="form_html">
<form name="form" action="PAGINA" method="post" id="se-form" data-toggle="validator">
            <div class="row">

                <div id="div_senha_usuario" class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Senha usuario</label>
                    <input type="text" name="senha_usuario" class="form-control tipo_senha_usuario " id="senha_usuario" required="">    
                    <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>      
                </div>
                <div id="div_data_cadastro" class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Data cadastro</label>
                    <input type="text" name="data_cadastro" class="form-control tipo_data_cadastro " id="data_cadastro" required="">    
                    <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>      
                </div>
                <div id="div_sec_atual" class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Sec atual</label>
                    <input type="text" name="sec_atual" class="form-control tipo_sec_atual " id="sec_atual" required="">    
                    <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>      
                </div>
                <div id="div_status_conta" class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Status conta</label>
                    <input type="text" name="status_conta" class="form-control tipo_status_conta " id="status_conta" required="">    
                    <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>      
                </div>                    
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                  <button class="btn btn-danger">Ação do botão</button>     
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode conseguir isso utilizando a função [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) para conseguir o elemento do qual deseja o código fonte e depois o atributo [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)  para conseguir a informação desejada. No exemplo abaixo imprimi a informação em um `console.log`, mas você pode usá-la como desejar.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('form_html').outerHTML);
```

```html
<div>
  Conteúdo irrelevante
  <div id="form_html">
    <form name="form" action="PAGINA" method="post" id="se-form" data-toggle="validator">
      <div class="row">

        <div id="div_senha_usuario" class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label>Senha usuario</label>
          <input type="text" name="senha_usuario" class="form-control tipo_senha_usuario " id="senha_usuario" required="">
          <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="div_data_cadastro" class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label>Data cadastro</label>
          <input type="text" name="data_cadastro" class="form-control tipo_data_cadastro " id="data_cadastro" required="">
          <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="div_sec_atual" class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label>Sec atual</label>
          <input type="text" name="sec_atual" class="form-control tipo_sec_atual " id="sec_atual" required="">
          <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="div_status_conta" class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label>Status conta</label>
          <input type="text" name="status_conta" class="form-control tipo_status_conta " id="status_conta" required="">
          <div class="help-block with-errors se-text-p"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
          <button class="btn btn-danger">Ação do botão</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

> [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
>
> Retorna o primeiro elemento dentro do documento (usando ordenação em profundidade, pré-ordenada e transversal dos nós do documento) que corresponde ao grupo especificado de seletores.

---

> [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)
>
> O atributo `outerHTML` da estrutura DOM(Document object model) obtem  um fragmento serializado de código HTML descrevendo o elemento incluindo seus descendentes. É possível substituir o elemento em questão com nós obtidos através da análise de uma string.

Comment: Obrigado @Sorack funcionou perfeitamente